# Is there a method or a xml value to check the remaining space of a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

[image: remaining space for more items]

[Android, layouts, cards, buttons]

In the image shown the remaining space is different for each device size, resolution or direction.

1. How can this remaining space be determined programmatically ?
2. Is there a xml value which can be added to the view (here button) to turn off the visibility if the remaining space is to small for a view (here button) to fit ?

(I know, In material.io perspective, I should not have more than two buttons in the bottom of a card, in this scenario the width of the card can be so narrow that the "v MORE" button also don't fit. Then I want the "v MORE" button do disappear, and I can show it as a menu entry in the popupmenu when clicking the overflow icon-button to the right.

I also know that an appearant suggestion is to use a menu line in the card, I don't like that, and it isn't good practice according to the material.io standards.)

Answer (score 0):

you can get device width by using  `Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;`

If u can guess more button disappearing logic using a screen width, use that and do the hide and other menu related changes based on that.

In addition to that, u can create same layout file for different screen sizes that are rendered using android according to that screen size. U can see how to make those in here https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

If you want to get starting and ending coordinates of that XML element u can use below code

```
Button moreButton = findViewbyId(R.id.thatButton);
int xStart=moreButton.getLeft();  
int yStart =moreButton.getTop(); 
int xEnd=moreButton.getRight();  
int yEnd =moreButton.getBottom();
```

then u can calculate what u want..